# Why does Orika map unused fields of nested List as null?

Tags: java, orika

Two entities: `Customer`, `CustomerAddress` - `Customer` has `List<CustomerAddress>`

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to CustomerAddress
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CustomerAddress> customeraddresses;

    private String identifier;

    private String aliasId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private Date createdDateTime;

    // Getters and Setters
}
public class CustomerAddress implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String line;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Customer
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customerId")
    private Customer customer;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private Date createdDateTime;

    private String gisLocation;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Corresponding DTOs:

```
public class CustomerDTO {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String aliasId;
    private List<CustomerAddressDTO> customeraddresses;
    // Getters and Setters
}
public class CustomerAddressDTO {
    private int id;
    private String line;
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Note: There are unused/extra fields in entity which are not used in DTO

Snippet from Update method:

```
Customer oldCustomer = customerDao.getCustomerById(dto.getId());
mapper.map(dto, oldCustomer);
```

Now, after this mapper call, the unused fields in List are set to null (which is not right)

What is the correct to ensure Orika preserves the unused fields on nested list?

---

(Additional information, if needed):

```
oldCustomer before mapping: Customer [id=2, name=Customer1, customeraddresses=[CustomerAddress [id=7, line=ABCD**, createdDateTime=Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2000, gisLocation=1], CustomerAddress [id=13, line=0000, createdDateTime=Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2001, gisLocation=2]], identifier=id1, aliasId=1234, createdDateTime=Tue Dec 12 00:00:00 IST 2000]
dto used for mapping: CustomerDTO [id=2, name=Customer1, aliasId=1234, customeraddresses=[CustomerAddressDTO [id=7, line=ABCD**], CustomerAddressDTO [id=13, line=0000]]]
oldCustomer after mapping: Customer [id=2, name=Customer1, customeraddresses=[CustomerAddress [id=7, line=ABCD**, createdDateTime=null, gisLocation=null], CustomerAddress [id=13, line=0000, createdDateTime=null, gisLocation=null]], identifier=id1, aliasId=1234, createdDateTime=Tue Dec 12 00:00:00 IST 2000]
```

(Note: `createdDateTime` aand `gisLocation` are set to null - these should retain original values)

Comment: After more investigation, it seems Orika is creating a new List<CustomerAddress> rather than mapping into the list that already exists

Comment: Logged as bug for orika: https://code.google.com/p/orika/issues/detail?id=181

Answer (score 0):

In Orika this is the default behavior you can also customize this by providing a mapper that merge two collection. there is example in the test code of the project.

Please check this example : [CustomMerge](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/master/tests/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/test/community/CustomMergerTest.java#L157)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looking at the example, it seems we will need to provide a custom mapper for every entity-dto pair. This seems too effort intensive. It will good to have a generic in-built merging algorithm.

Comment: There is no need to do this for each DTO/Entity pair, if you have interface for getId (for example).

BTW there is no generic merge, it depends on your strategy, if you want drop-out-replace, cumulative or reconciliation ... The strategy you described is more a reconciliation one, for reconciliation you need an unique identifier to match dto with entity for which you need to do copy. It's more an app problem rather than generic one as it adds cost developer should be aware of. We try to keep such choices out of the library, but maybe we can provide some strategies to improve productivity